# Accessing Linq data in telerik grid ItemCreated method

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, data-binding, telerik

Not sure if the title of this question makes sense, but here's my problem:

I have a telerik grid bound to a Linq data object, however, I limit the fields returned:

```
<IQueryable>filter = data.Select(x => new {x.ID, x.Name, x.Age});
```

I would like to access these fields in the ItemCreated method of the grid:

```
protected void rgPeople_ItemCreated(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
  Telerik.Web.UI.GridDataItem item = (GridDataItem)e.Item;
  ?????? Person = (???????)e.Item.DataItem;
}
```

What do I declare ?????? as so that I can use:

```
String ID = Person.ID;
String Name = Person.Name; etc
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I was able to do what you wanted in the ItemDataBound event handler. Below is a portion of my code.

```
protected void grMain_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
    {
          GridDataItem item = (GridDataItem)e.Item;
          //Now I can get at the object from the list that the row is bound to
          PricingCandidate candidate = (PricingCandidate)e.Item.DataItem;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
protected void rgPeople_ItemCreated(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
   if(e.Item.ItemType = GridItemType.AlternatingItem Or e.Item.ItemType =                          GridItemType.Item)
    {    
        Telerik.WebControls.GridDataItem item = e.Item;

        Label lbl as Label;

        lbl= item("ColumnName").FindControl("lblName")



    }
}
```

Juding by what you want to nkow how to do - perhaps you should be performing your task on the OnRowDataBinding event.

Answer (score 0):

No, I didn't miss your point.  A Label is as much of an object as a GridDataItem, or your "Person" object.  I understand that your point is to be spoonfed a solution, so here you go.

```
protected void rgPeople_ItemCreated(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{   
    if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
    {
        var item = ((GridDataItem)e.Item);
        Hashtable values = new Hashtable();
        item.ExtractValues(values);
        string Name = (string)values["Name"];
        string ID = (string)values["ID"];
        string Age = (string)values["Age"];
    }
 }
```

Comment: Or instead of the hashtable, did you try 

Person person = (Person)((GridDataItem)e.Item);